# Apple Seach Ads Discovery Campaigns stuck at Pending audience size verification

Tags: ios, discovery, apple-search-ads

I went through documentation on different websites (including Apple) about the Apple Search Ads Advanced engine. I have an iOS app that I want to promote but I am not sure about the keywords I should choose. I've read that I can start what's called a Discovery Campaign. As I understand it, I start a campaign with Search Match enabled (and no keywords set?) so Apple can discovery keywords for me based on my app's meta data.

I did a campaign with a small budget to test it. After a couple of days, it says my campaign is running but my adgroup status is stuck at "Pending audience size verification". Can anyone explain me what's going on? I am a bit lost as I can't find any infos on this. Do I have to pre-define keywords to get the algorithm started? As this is a discovery, I want to discover  keywords so I didn't put any. Or is my CPT max bid too low so it doesn't generate traffic?

Thanks a lot for any insight on this!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who might have a similar issue than a I had, I've found the answer to my own problem.

I've tried increasing the CPT thinking that might have been the issue. The real problem was that for the ad group I've set the algorithm to look for the users who uses some of my other apps. These apps I selected might not have enough users (or the volume of searches might not be enough) to create a discovery campaign. As soon as I switched it to all users, the ad was working.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you can't promote a new app to users of your other apps... I tried doing the same thing and got the same error  "Pending audience size verification" ... what if I only want users of my other apps to see my ad !!?